# Next-auth Package subpath '.providers/...' is not defined by "exports" in

Tags: next.js, next-auth

Just got this error while working with Next-auth

> Server Error
>
> Error: Package subpath './providers/google' is not defined by "exports" in C:\Users...\node_modules\next-auth\package.json

Any help?

Comment: I'm facing similar issue with CredentialProvider. Were you able to do it without downgrading Next Auth?

Answer (score 1):

I think this comes from your next-auth version.
Make sure you're not working with mixed versions' features.

We now have two main versions: Version 3 and Version 4 (beta version).

By Reading the Docs, You can figure it out.

[Check this Thread and use the Link to know more about this version issue](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/2697#issuecomment-915094099)

You can solve the problem by upgrading the Version  [Upgrade your Next-auth for some compatibilities issues](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/upgrade-v4)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, and in my particular case are be because i been running a old version of node.

first check your version of node

```
node -v
```

after upgrate with your package manager of your preference (brew, apt-get, etc)

```
brew upgrade node
```

and finally switch your version with a version manager tool of node

```
npm i -g n
n latest
```

Answer (score 0):

for me updating the node version fixed the above issue

Answer (score 0):

yes, I have the same issue as this, don't panic.

I solved just trying to install and reinstall node_module.

- case 1 remove node_module and install again use npm (install success install not information error)
- case 2 remove node_module again and install node_module use yarn ( I getting some information error for requiring version nodejs version), so in this case you need to upgrade or downgrade nodejs to another version.

okay that it, I hope this help you.

Comment: I don't think you even need to reinstall. Just running `npm install` was good enough for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
```